# Http requests fails only while releasing Android build APK but works while debugging

Tags: angular, nativescript-angular, angular-nativescript

All the API calls are working in debugging but when I am creating a build apk file, request not even get called in build apk. The server has an SSL certificate still it get failed

Answer (score 1):

Add **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"** in the application tag of **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
----
----
</application>
```